# How to make a filter from two lists? Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

There are two lists. Users are listed in the first list. And the second list shows the types of events. The filter should work like this:
User selected the user from the first list and selected the type of the event from the second list. Then a table with the names of the events appears. And based on the selected user and the type of event, the table will display the name of the event. To implement this there are such models (I will not add the entire model to the question, I will add only the keys):

user.model:

```
export class User{
    constructor(
        public user_id?:number,
        ....
    ) { }
}
```

type-event.model:

```
export class TypeEvent{
    constructor(
        public typeevent_id?: number,
        ...
    ) { }
}
```

name-event.model

```
export class NameEvent{
    constructor(
        public events_id?:number,
        public l_typeevents_id?: number,
        public name?: string
    ) { }
}
```

event-user.model:

```
export class EventUser{
    constructor(
        public events_id?:number,
        public l_typeevents_id?: number,
        public user_id?: number,
        public full_name?: string,
        public is_check?: number
    ) { }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="list-group" >
  <div class="media" *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers">
    <a class="{{selectedUser == user ? 'active' : ''}} list-group-item" (click)="onSelectedUser(user.user_id)"> 
      <h4 class=" media-heading list-group-item-heading"> {{user.full_name}} 
      </h4>
    </a>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="card" *ngIf="selectedUser">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let typeEvent of typeEvents">
      <div class="card card-stats" >
        <a class="{{selectedTypeEvent == typeEvent ? 'active' : ''}} list-group-item" (click)="onSelectedTypeEvent(typeEvent.typeevent_id)">
           <div class="card-content">
             <h4 class="title" style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer; " >
               {{typeEvent.name}}
             </h4>
           </div>
         </a>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="selectedTypeEvent">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead >
        <tr>
         <th>
           Name Event
         </th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let nameEvent of filteredNameEvents">   
           <td>
             {{nameEvent.name}}
           </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
  users: Array<User>;
  typeEvents: Array<TypeEvent>;
  nameEvents: Array<NameEvent>;
  eventUsers: Array<EventUser>;
  isNewRecord: boolean;
  selectedUser = null;
  filteredUsers = [];
  selectedTypeEvent = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadUsers();
    this.loadTypeEvents();
    this.loadNameEvents();
    this.loadEventUser();
  }

  private loadUsers() {
    this.loading = true;
    let filteredUsers;
    if (this.servUser) {
      this.servUser.getUsers().subscribe(
        user => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.users = user;
          this.filteredUsers = this.users.filter(
            (user) => user.is_events ==  'Y'
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }

  private loadEventUser() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.servEventUser.getEventUsers().subscribe(
      (data: EventUser[]) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.eventUsers = data;
      }
    )
  }


  private loadTypeEvents() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.servTypeEvent.getTypeEvents().subscribe(
      (data: TypeEvent[]) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.typeEvents = data;  
      }
    );
  }

  private loadNameEvents() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.servNameEvent.getNameEvents().subscribe(
      (data: NameEvent[]) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.nameEvents = data;  
      }
    );
  }




  onSelectedTypeEvent(typeEventId) {
    this.selectedTypeEvent = this.typeEvents.find(
      el => {
        return el.typeevent_id === typeEventId
      }
    );
    let filteredNameEvents;
    if (this.servNameEvent) {
      this.servNameEvent.getNameEvents().subscribe(
        nameEvent => {
          this.nameEvents = nameEvent;
          this.filteredNameEvents = this.nameEvents.filter(
            (nameEvent) => nameEvent.l_typeevents_id == this.selectedTypeEvent.typeevent_id
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }


  onSelectedUser(userId) {
    this.selectedUser = this.filteredUsers.find(
      el => {
        return el.user_id === userId
      }
    );
  }
```

Based on these models, how can make such a filter? I'm already in a stupor, could you give me at least a hint?

Comment: It is hard to provide any details unless you show us your code and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Why are you getting issue to show it ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I can only make a filter by type of event. and to make so that filtering still occurred on users I do not know. Do you still need to demonstrate your code for this?

Comment: @PramodPatil what do you mean?

Comment: @user10309896 show us the code where are you doing filtering, so that we can help. Without code it's hard to understand your problem. 
We know you are new here, you can go through few existing quetions and get how others described their problem.

Comment: @PratapA.K added the code to  question

Answer (score 0):

I don't have complete picture on you problem statement. But this is how it's usually done

```
export class EventManager {
  userList string[] = [];
  eventList string[] = [];

  eventTable = [];

  filterEvents(user, event) {
   your logic goes here
  }

 onUserChange() {
  ... filter events
 }

  onEventChange() {
    ... filter events
   }
}
```

**Html**

```
<select [ngModel]="user" (ngModelChange)="onUserChange($event)">
<option *ngFor="let user of userList "></option>
</select>

<select [ngModel]="event" (ngModelChange)="onEventChange($event)">
<option *ngFor="let event of eventList "></option>
</select>
```

**Sample filter code:**

```
1. userList.filter((user) => user === 'russiauser'); 

2. userList.filter((user) => user === 'russiauser' || user === 'indiauser');
```

you can filter the list (array) using **filter** function and it returns array

Comment: I can not write the logic itself, not the structure. I do not know how to write a filter for users and event types to display the name of the event itself for these models.

Comment: use filter function to filter items. It's simple

Comment: I honestly do not understand anything in the "NameEvent" model, there is no identifier for the users of the model, and how to do this for this filter?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your design, it seems like you are trying to select **one** user, and based on that you can then select **one** event type. After the event type is selected, you then list the events based on that event type.
If those assumptions correct, you may need to refactor your code.

```
onSelectedUser(userId) {
    this.selectedUser = this.filteredUsers.find(
      el => {
        return el.user_id === userId
      }
    );
  }
```

can be just

```
 onSelectedUser(userId) {
    this.selectedUser = userId;
    loadTypeEvents(userId);
  }
```

because `selectedUser` now have value your list of types can be displayed.

```
private loadTypeEvents() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.servTypeEvent.getTypeEvents().subscribe(
      (data: TypeEvent[]) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.typeEvents = data;  
      }
    );
  }
```

can be refactored to

```
 loadTypeEvents() {
    this.loading = true;
    return this.servTypeEvent.getTypeEvents().pipe(
      filter(event=> event.typeUserId == this.selectedUser
    );
  }
```

You can then use it in you HTML with async pipe.

And the list continues.... If you want, you can create a stackblitz with your code in it and I can work with you on resolving you problems.